# ora-06502 on writing into LONG variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Here's a simplified request:

```
declare
  long_var long;
begin
  select long_column into long_var from my_table where id = 1;
end;
```

It works for most cases but when the long_column value is too big (I've found at least one entry - it has a value of about 5 megabytes) causes

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Oracle PL/SQL documentation

> You cannot retrieve a value longer than 32,760 bytes from a LONG or LONG RAW column into a LONG or LONG RAW variable.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#CJAEGDEB

You can use a CLOB but you must alter the column from LONG to CLOB

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY ( long_column CLOB );
```

Then you use:

```
declare
  clob_var clob;
begin
  select long_column into clob_var from my_table where id = 1;
end;
```

If you cannot change the table copy it over:

1) Create table with a CLOB

```
create table my_table_2 (clob_column clob, id number);
```

2) Copy it over

```
insert into my_table_2 
select to_lob(long_column), id from my_table;
```

3) Access the new table

```
declare
  clob_var clob;
begin
  select clob_column into clob_var from my_table_2 where id = 1;
end;
```

Comment: But I already have LONG in database. using clob variable causes: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG

Comment: You are right. I made an edit. LONG columns cannot be read into CLOB. Oracle provides the `to_lob` but it can only be used to when inserting from a table with a `LONG` to a table with a `CLOB`.